# parse and updating xml file from a text file in shell script (using xmlstarlet)

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xmlstarlet

I have an xml file and i would like to change node value depending on values from a text file.
So basically this is xml file --> 001.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orderfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:38:00</ establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610009-01</identification>
  </order>
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:40:00</ establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610910-03</identification>
  </order>
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:42:00</ establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610015-01</identification>
  </order>
```

And this is my text file

```
170610009-01;2017-06-21
170610015-01;2017-02-22
```

What I would like to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orderfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:38:00</establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate>2017-06-21</ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610009-01</identification>
  </order>
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:40:00</ establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610910-03</identification>
  </order>
  <order>
    <establishmenthour>10:42:00</ establishmenthour>
    <ExpirationDate>2017-02-22</ExpirationDate/>
    <acc/>
    <identification>170610015-01</identification>
  </order>
```

I decided to write a bash scrip using xmlstarlet but it seems to not work

```
 #!/bin/bash

    while read line; do

       last10=${line:14:23}
       first12=${line:0:12}

    if /orderFile/order[identification = '${first12}']
    then xmlstarlet ed -u /orderFile/order[@expirationDate]/@expirationDate -v "${last10}"  001.xml
fi
    done < datevalid.txt
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is `if /orderFile/order[identification = '${first12}']` supposed to do?

Comment: @123 check if the identification with the first 12 characters from the text file exist and if so update the value in the node "expiraionDate".